# Connect two Google Sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I want to create a sheet by `SpreadsheetApp.create();` and to fill a QUERY in this new generated sheet via `cell.setFormula` and IMPORTRANGE to get data of another Sheet.

It doesn't work because the sheets are not connected. If I do so manually the QUERY works.

Is there a way to connect two sheets via script?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable with the locations of the sheets by the ID's. Then, access the sheet remotely via the script. Save the cell variable and paste this over into the first sheet.

**Psuedo-Code Example**

```
Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByID('IDofSheetOne');
SpreadsheetApp.create();
Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByID('IDofSheetTwo'); // the one just created, you'd probably have to use some kind of get to get this ID.
```

Now from here, you can just say, Sheet1.doWhatever() and Sheet2.doWhatever().

Thats how you can access more than one sheet at a time.

Comment: I pasted the code correctly, the problem is - I have to go into the sheet manually and connect both sheets so the query/importrange works. 
As I understand your idea, it seems to do basically the same?

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean 'manually'? If sheet1 is the one you have open, get the ID of the active sheet. If sheet2 is the one you created, get the ID of the one you just created. You can do this by using 'get' commands in google app script. Then from there, you can just use sheet1 and sheet2 to have them update. You could have the function fire onEdit() and it would be even more 'automatic'

Comment: If I create a Sheet1 which refers to data from Sheet2 via importRange you have to go into the sheet1 and connect both sheets. ATM I see no way to auto-connect a new created sheet with an existing one via script - is that right?

Comment: You mean to have them have the same exact value even if you change one side? @dirtybob